# Replicate 'docker volume create --name data' command on docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm building my containers with `docker-compose` and I would like to use the new volume API from Docker, but I don't see how to.

I want to be able to say `docker-compose up -d` to:

- Create a volume, or use it if already created.
- Create services containers with data from previous volume container.

Comment: See the Compose file documentation, specifically the sections on volumes and volumes_from: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all you must be using a version 2 Compose file to use the new specifications for creating and using named volumes. The [Compose File Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#version-2) includes all you need to know, including examples.

To summarize:

1. Add `version: '2'` to the top of `docker-compose.yml`.
2. Place service units under a `services:` key.
3. Place volume units under a `volumes:` key.
4. When referring to a named volume from a service unit, specify `volumename:/path` where `volumename` is the name given under the `volumes:` key (in the example below it is `dbdata`) and `/path` is the location inside the container of the mounted volume (e.g., `/var/lib/mysql`).

Here's a minimal example that creates a named volume `dbdata` and references it from the `db` service.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  dbdata:
    driver: local
```