# Docker bind elasticsearch volume in app folder

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file :

```
version: "3.3"
services:    
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9300:9300"
      - "9200:9200"

volumes:
  esdata:
```

(I removed other services for clarity)
I can see the volume in /var/lib/docker/volumes/**project_name**_esdata but I would like to be able to create the volume in the directory where the docker-compose.yml is but I didn't find a way to do so.

Inspired from [How to set a path on host for a named volume in docker-compose.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387032/how-to-set-a-path-on-host-for-a-named-volume-in-docker-compose-yml), I tried

```
version: "3.3"
services:    
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.1
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9300:9300"
      - "9200:9200"

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: './'
```

But that raise the following exception :

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes
```

Please, let me know if I should post the full stack trace or any other relevant informations.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you use ./ the volume will be mounted in the same folder (I have had permissions issues before by doing this just so you know)

```
version: "3.3"
services:    
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.1
    volumes:
      - ./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9300:9300"
      - "9200:9200"

volumes:
  esdata:
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there a way to still do so ? I am thinking about some command that would allow the folder to be read.
for instance, I also run a mongodb container, and there is no issue putting volume in the app folder

Comment: yes, like I mentioned, add . to the first volumes line (./esdata). That mounts the volume in the same folder.

Comment: Yes good call, I'll accept your answer since unlike the other one,it  has the advantage of dealing with relative paths.
And my apologies, I didn' read your answer thoroughly the first time since I was pretty sure that I had already tried the `./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data`

Answer (score 4):

This answer is applicable for ElasticSearch 7.14. As, other users have mentioned, you can get the volume to be created under the same directory as `docker-compose.yml` using relative path notation. i.e, an entry like this:

> ```
> volumes:
>       - ./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
> ```

will cause the `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data` directory within the elastic search container to be loaded onto  the `./esdata` directory in the host. Here, `.` is the directory where the `docker-compose.yml` is present. There's an important catch though. The `./esdata` directory should be owned by `elasticsearch:elasticsearch` mapping to `uid:gid = 1000:1000`. So, it's mandatory that the `elasticsearch:elasticsearch` user with the exact uid:gid is present on the host.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is almost ok but you need to use absolute path as `device: ./` is causing mount of root file system instead of current directory (that's why you receive access denied)

Use absolute path in device like `device: /opt/your-project/data` - please also note that directory must exist before use.