# Docker compose volume: copying folder from docker container to host when executing docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-volume

I have this simple `docker-compose.yaml` (image from [danielemaddaluno/self-service-password](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/danielemaddaluno/self-service-password)):

```
version: "3"
services:
  ltb:
      image: danielemaddaluno/self-service-password
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      volumes:
        - ./conf:/var/www/html/conf/
```

The current behaviour is that:

- if the `./conf` doesn't exist, it is created on the host
- and the empty content is mounted in the container at `/var/www/html/conf/`

The behaviour that I wanted it's that:

- if the `./conf` doesn't exist, it is created on the host
- and the content is firstly loaded from container's `/var/www/html/conf/` (to the newly created `./conf` host's folder)

Is this possible with docker compose?

Answer (score 4):

This is possible but only with `volume` mounts: `docker` and thus `docker-compose` distinguishes between [(named) `volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes) and [`bind mounts`](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), most notably:

> - New **volumes** can have their content pre-populated by a container.

With `bind mounts` you specify an absolute path to a directory or file on the `docker` host to be bind-mounted into the container.

Technically `volumes` do the same with the difference that the source directory/file on the host is completely managed by `docker`, i.e. you can [create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/)/[list](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/)/[delete](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_rm/) them with the `docker volume` command. This allows `docker` to provide additional features for those `volumes`, e.g. to [populate the volume with the contents of the container image at the target directory in the image](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container) when the volume is first created.

In contrast using [a `bind mount` will always override/hide](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container) the contents of the target path.

To use a named volume use this `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  ltb:
      image: danielemaddaluno/self-service-password
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      volumes:
        - conf:/var/www/html/conf/

volumes:
  conf:
```

This will automatically create a new named volume `conf` and populate it with the contents of `/var/www/html/conf/` of the `danielemaddaluno/self-service-password` **when you first start it** - i.e. subsequent runs will reuse the existing volume and not copy the contents again!

---

If using a `volume` is not feasible for you but you must use a `bind mount` you'll have to manage the initialization/population of the volume yourself, e.g. by using an entrypoint script to copy files from the container into an empty volume.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. That seems exactly what I needed. I'm a little bit new on docker, I tried launching a `docker-compose up` on your suggested `docker-compose.yml` (the one with `volumes: conf:`) but no folder it's created... Am I missing something? Where is the new named volume conf located? Can I locate it in the same folder of the yaml as I did with my yaml?

Comment: Well, that's exactly the drawback: when using a named volume the underlying source directory (or file) is completely managed by `docker` and is not placed in your project directory but somewhere else, e.g. under `/var/lib/docker`, depending on the used volume driver.
If you _really_ need to access the volume directly on the host / need to place it at a specific path - and chances are you actually don't - use a `bind mount` with some custom initialisation (e.g. using an entrypoint script, initiailisation service)

Comment: You could also bend the `local` volume driver to use a specific path on the host, [see this e.g. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49920624/11932806). But I would **really not** recommend this, especially for a beginner! Instead try to get familiar with named volumes and how to use them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this is not possible.
The reason is that docker-compose maps the folder in the container to the host folder and overwrites what was originally in the image.

If you want to have the default conf file on your host, a better way is to first leave out the volumes mapping, then exec into the container, copy that conf file and create it on the host conf-folder.

From then on the conf file is available.

Also, you map './conf' (without trailing slash) to a folder (with trailing slash) in the container. Don't know if this works and I would keep the trialing slash in sync between host and container in the volume definition.